# How to find all items in a bindinglist that have been changed

Tags: vb.net

I have an OrderItems class that inherits BindingList.  It stores a list of Order lines.  These are presented in a DataGridView.  The user can directly access the DGV and update values of each row and add new row.

[image: Data Grid View with a message box showing iteration of bindinglist objects]

When the user uses a "Save" button, I want to find all the rows that have changed, so I can then process them.  How can I do that?

One idea I've had is to when instantiating the OrderItem Object, I keep another list in the OrderItems object to store original values, then iterate though the bindingList comparing against the original values in the other list?  Seems a bit wasteful and intensive but there'll be only 10 or so items in the binding list.

Or should I have another field in the bindingList Object to store a flag that I'd have to set when a user changes a value in one of the rows cells (if so what event would be the best?), then iterate though the bindinglist, look for items with the flag set and just process them?

Its been a bit of a struggle understanding the DGV/Binding process, so I'd appreciate some guidance. I have looked online but most guides seem to deal with datatables/views and C#

Comment: Have you considered modifying the entities to add change tracking to them?

Comment: You basically just need a flag in item class that is `False` by default and that you set to `True` in the setter of each property. You can the expose that flag via a `ReadOnly` property.  You then just save those items for which that flag is `True`.

Comment: @jmcilhinney Sounds good.  However, I use the setter when creating the list of ojects in the first place so they would all show up as True after I collect the data from the database to populate the list? Or, I set the flag to false after creating each object (but then it wouldnt be readonly)?

Comment: You could either provide a constructor that has a parameter for each property so you can create the objects without setting the properties directly, or you could provide something akin to the `AcceptChanges` method of the `DataRow` class, which resets the `RowState` property to `Unchanged`.

Comment: @jmcilhinney  Thanks.  Understand the constructor approach.  DataRow class - thats for datasets etc?  I'm using bindinglist.  But I'll have a look. thanks again.

Comment: Yes, a `DataRow` is basically an item in a list and a `DataTable` is that list. You would provide functionality in the items in your list that it does for the same reason that it does.